# Area Blue outlining in HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, area

I am looking at HTML  hot spots and have a question with regards to an example I have found on a previous Stack Overflow Q&A.

[Previous Stack OverFlow Area Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617957/how-to-make-text-box-appear-when-hover-over-on-the-image-map)

In the first answer from 'Gibberish' he has provided a worked example on JSFiddle. [JSFiddle Example from Gibberish](http://jsfiddle.net/scuxp/)

```js
function hovIn() {
  var areaID = $(this).attr('id');
  //alert('['+areaID+']');
  if (areaID == 'CUST_1') {
    $('#myDiv').show();
  }
}

function hovOut() {
  $('#myDiv').hide();
}

$('map area').hover(hovIn, hovOut);
```

```css
#num_cust1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 180px;
}

#num_cust2 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: 40px;
}

#num_cust3 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 180px;
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Instructions: Mouse over computer's monitor to see hidden DIV
<!--<img src="http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/upload/yuiupload/2014513384.jpg" width="400" height="400" />-->
<div id="imagemap">
  <img src="http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/8287/3ylp.jpg" width="275" height="207" usemap="#Map" border="0" />
  <map name="Map">
        <area shape="poly" coords="105,26,107,126,257,140,256,27" href="#" id="CUST_1" name="CUST:1" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="10,21,14,178,71,184,69,19" href="#" id="CUST_2" name="CUST:2" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="113,145,94,172,241,192,251,164,250,164" href="#" id="CUST_3" name="CUST:3" />
    </map>
  <p>
    <div id="myDiv">This DIV hidden unless hover over the computer's monitor</div>
  </p>
</div>
<!-- Yellow DIV ID numbers overlaid on top of computer components -->
<div id="num_cust1">1</div>
<div id="num_cust2">2</div>
<div id="num_cust3">3</div>
```

I understand how most of the answer works apart from, if I click on any of the three defined Polygon areas they become highlighted by a blue outline - but I can't see the code that makes this happen (e.g. a click event). Can anyone explain how/why they show up blue without any code (that I can see)??

Screen grab of Fiddle output with blue clicked area shown:

[image: 1]

Comment: When you use the `<area>` tag, it automatically lets you select it and it adds  the default blue border around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **map** tag is used to define a client-side image-map. An image-map is an image with clickable areas.

The required name attribute of the **map** element is associated with the **img's** usemap attribute and creates a relationship between the image and the map.

The **map** element contains a number of **area** elements, that defines the clickable areas in the image map.

To hide the outline you can do

```css
map area {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<map name="primary">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" href="#">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" href="#">
</map>
<img usemap="#primary" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
```

Using the [outine](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) css property you can do a lot of stuff to the map area.For example you want to change the color from `blue` to `red` you can do

```css
map area{
outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<map name="primary">
  <area shape="circle" coords="75,75,75" href="#">
  <area shape="circle" coords="275,75,75" href="#">
</map>
<img usemap="#primary" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their responses in answering my initial question - you guys are awesome.. Is there a method to always show a hotspot area (e.g. a constant border without a click or even opacity colour fill to highlight an area is that is clickable) as opposed to it only being shown when clicked???

Comment: @Mikeyd If this answer was helpful then upvote and mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the browser handles clicking on **map area** and you'll see that if you try it in Internet Explorer you'll get a dotted line. In Chrome you will receive a blue outline and in FireFox you won't get one!

It's handled similar to a button.

the following CSS will remove the outline:

```
map area{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by

```
outline:none;
```